# Generating a list of integers that isn't equal to a specified integer in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, generator, quickcheck

Is there a modifier that allows me to generate a list of integers that does not contain a specified integer?

This is a function that does the same job:

```
listofInts :: Int -> Gen [Integer]
listofInts  a = rmInt a [] arbitrary

rmInt :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
rmInt a newList [] = newList
rmInt a newList (x:xs)
|a == x = newList : rmInt a xs
|otherwise = newList : x : rmInt a xs
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `listOf` and `suchThat` combinators from [`Test.QuickCheck.Gen`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.8.1/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Gen.html) should enable you to do that.

```
listofInts :: Int -> Gen [Integer]
listOfInts x = listOf (suchThat arbitrary (/=x))
```

This approach have the advantage to be more respectful of the size parameter for the generation: `suchThat` ensures that a generated value that doesn't match the predicate does not influence the size.

Comment: Good idea! I suppose `suchThat` also lends itself to infix notation, `arbitrary \`suchThat\` (/= x)` is kinda nice.

Answer (score 6):

I assume that you actually meant `Gen [Int]` when you wrote `Gen [Integer]`. You can simply filter the generated list:

```
listofInts :: Int -> Gen [Int]
listofInts x = filter (/= x) <$> arbitrary
```